# PHP display images if $value = $string?

Tags: php, html, image, if-statement

I need to know if there's a quickest and efficient way to display one or more images if `$value == $string`

For example: I have an cell which only contains 3 single string: `'r o g'`, if user put `ro` it will output `<img src="red.gif">` and `<img src="orange.gif">` So it could be random if user insert `gr` then it will display `<img src="green.gif">` and `<img src="red.gif">`

Right now I can only think something like...

```
<?php $red = "<img src="red.gif">";
$orange = "<img src="orange.gif">";
if( $cell1 == $red ){ echo $red;}
if( $cell1 == $red && $orange ){ echo $orange.$red;}
etc...
```

This method might works but has to provide too many possibility and I believe there's a shorter and efficient to do that, but I haven't got any idea because still I'm learning PHP

Comment: User can put only two of the three characters right?

Comment: can be 0 and max 3 characters for now

Comment: How it should respond if they put nothing?

Comment: It will response nothing @PradeepSambandam

Comment: Simply don't concatenate your output and have 3 if statements, one for each color. `if (strpos($cell1, "r") !== false) { echo "<img src=\"red.gif\">"; }` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this approach?

```
<?php

//define all your images here
$images = [
    'r' => 'red.png',
    'g' => 'green.png',
    'b' => 'blue.png',
    'y' => 'yellow.png',
    'o' => 'orange.png'
];

function output($input, $images) {
    $parts = str_split($input);
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (isset($images[$part]))
            echo '<img src="' . $images[$part] . '">';
    }
}

echo "rgb: \n";
output('rgb', $images);

echo "\n\nyor: \n";
output('yor', $images);

echo "\n\nxxy: \n";
output('xxy', $images);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/b43ff627317052):

```
rgb: 
<img src="red.png"><img src="green.png"><img src="blue.png">

yor: 
<img src="yellow.png"><img src="orange.png"><img src="red.png">

xxy: 
<img src="yellow.png">
```

Comment: this is clean I like it

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= strlen( $cell1 ); $i++ ) {
    $char = substr( $cell1, $i, 1 );
    switch ($char) {
        case "r":
            echo '<img src="red.gif">';
            break;
        case "o":
            echo '<img src="orange.gif">';
            break;
        case "g":
            echo '<img src="green.gif">';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that shows an example for 3 character inputs. $string can be the posted value.

```
$r = '<img src="red.gif">';
$y = '<img src="yellow.gif">';
$o = '<img src="orange.gif">';
$g = '<img src="green.gif">';
$string = 'ryo';
$length = strlen($string);

for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
    echo ${''.$string[$i]};
}
```

Comment: I dont think you need to check the length, if its 0 then there won't be any iteration